# How to partition hard drive where already Ubuntu 16.04 is installed

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 16.04, gparted, disk-utility

I have installed `Ubuntu 16.04` in my whole laptop space. But right now , i have a requirement to install Windows in the same laptop. And since i am trying to install windows side by side with this Ubuntu version i tried to partition the hard drive space the current Ubuntu is installed in. However, i cannot partition the drive. So is there any way to do that?

P.S. I already tried using `g-parted` and `disk-utility` but neither of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to proceed like this:

1. Make sure there is enough space for your new partition.
2. Make a bootable USB stick of Ubuntu by following this [GUIDE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).
3. Boot via USB stick in live mode.
4. Open gparted and partition your drive.

When you boot via live mode, be sure not to mount your drive, else you'll not be able to modify the partitions.
If you do it, you'll need to unmount it via command line with the `umount` command.